# UI-router issue with transitionTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to use a route with variable parameters, that way I can use the parameters to check to which state to resolve.
I have made a simplified plunker which demonstrates what I am trying to do.
The problem is that the controllers of the targeted routes don't seem to be initiated. The resolves however are done.

Here is the code, below is a link to the plunker:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


  $stateProvider
    .state('default', {
      url: "/welcome",
      templateUrl: "def.html"
    })
    .state('redirect', {
      url: "/{param1}/{param2}",
      params: {
        param1: {
          value: 'foo'
        },
        param2: {
          value: 'bar'
        }
      },
      template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'
    })
    .state('redirect.first', {
      templateUrl: "route1.html"
    })
    .state('redirect.second', {
      templateUrl: "route2.html",
      controller: function() {
        console.log('in controller');
      },
      resolve: {
        test: function($stateParams) {
          console.log($stateParams);
          return 'test';
        }
      }
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})

.run(function($rootScope, $injector) {

  var $state = $injector.get('$state');

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log('entering state change start');
    if (toState.name == 'redirect') {
      $state.transitionTo('redirect.second', toParams, {
        location: true,
        inherit: true,
        reload: true,
        notify: true
      });
    }
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/3n5D3Q3i5XHRw38WFdz3?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we need is to stop the default navigation by **`event.preventDefault();`** *(here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qLU0VdpZO48BgW4N1cmi?p=preview))*

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState,   toParams
                                                  , fromState, fromParams){    
    if(toState.name == 'redirect'){
        // HERE
        // the default must be stop, to redirect...
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.transitionTo('redirect.second', toParams
             , { location:true, inherit:true, reload:true, notify:true });
    }
});
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qLU0VdpZO48BgW4N1cmi?p=preview)

Also check the [$urlRouter.sync()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#urlroutersync)

Comment: @ryeballar the plunker is not well designed, I showed only what is the issue asked in the question. The answer is: redirect could be done only if the default is prevented... If you know what I mean. But to make it working properly, states and navigation should be rewritten

Comment: Thanks, I know there are some issues in the Plunker, started from a template and made a quick fix. Will try this solution soon. Keep you updated.

Comment: @DriesMarien yeah, it would be good to know if you did it. The `ui-router` is great lib, and the best documentation I've seen ;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler your solution is working just fine! Thanks for your input!

Comment: Great to see that sir! :) Enjoy amazing `ui-router`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ui-sref="redirect.first"` syntax instead of `href="/"`

Here's working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wEU5RbCsp3LpeUHbKTo9?p=preview